# css transition from auto to any height, behavior is very inconsistent in safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

In Chrome if you have a transition height set, and go from `auto` to a value, or from a value to `auto`, it will not apply a transition, it will warp directly to the value you just set as if you had no transition set. I have not looked it up, I do suspect that this is a loophole in CSS spec. It sucks, but I can work around the failure of having a transition by cleverly calculating the height manually and applying sleight-of-hand.

So yes, I have a bunch of sophisticated UI code that makes this assumption, because there is no other way to implement certain smooth UI interactions.

Then Safari steps in at some point in the last few months, and deviates from this behavior with something going completely in the wrong direction. A total monkey wrench toss, this one.

If you go from `auto` to a value, it warps to `0`, then transitions to the value.

If you go from a value to `auto`, it transitions to `0`, then warps to the auto value.

Now....... I may just be going a little crazy here but I am pretty certain that a few months ago this was not how Safari behaved.

I am on Safari version 8.0.7 here on OS X Yosemite 10.10.4.

My question is -- is there some other CSS value I can use to bring back the normal (still not really sane, but more sane than *this*) behavior?

I am not looking for help with workarounds or any such. I can already think of several. I am mostly speaking out of the frustration caused by the introduction of fresh new browser fragmentation.

Answer (score 0):

This is Safari being overly helpful.

The reason this hack worked for you originally is that CSS can't transition to or from a non-numeric value as it's not calculable.

However, Safari is anticipating that you wouldn't have a transition on an element if you didn't want it to, y'know, *transition*.  So they helpfully apply a default value to the element prior to transition: auto.

If you don't want it to transition, you can try `inherit`, `none` or any other number of non-numeric – but valid! – CSS values (although these are likely to be shimmed to default to a number too, whether the inherited value or 0 again).

The better choice would be to set `transition: none` on items that you don't want to actually transition.

So I know you don't want workarounds, but setting `transition: none` on those elements that you specifically don't want to transition isn't a workaround.  It's just the correct behavior for your CSS.

Comment: Yeah but this means that I need another state flip here when Chrome doesn't require one. I actually have to set transition to none, call window.getComputedStyles(), then do the dirty business to set state without transition, then set it back. It's a goddamn headache... I guess I'll just do that now.